# jQuery datatables server side complex table creation

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables server side processing to build a table.

My json response is good I'm getting the right row information, paging is working too.

My issue is i want to manipulate the how the data is displayed in the table and i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

I've looked at the `columns.render` documentation https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

As well as the more detailed version
https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers

I cant seem to figure it out. I need my table to look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4eyQ.jpg

I have made this work with razor but the data load is way to slow hence i moved to data tables to procedurally load the information.

I've tried using the `render:function(data,type,row)` but i cant seem to figure it out. I'm thinking maybe i have to create the row manually in jQuery and then add and draw the table.

```
public JsonResult OnGetServerSideDataTable(DataTableAjaxModel ajaxModel)
        {
            List<DutyWeb> temp = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<DutyWeb>>("appsSession");
            //int filteredResult = 0;
            int totalResult = 0;

            totalResult = temp.Count;

            temp = temp.Skip(ajaxModel.start).Take(ajaxModel.length).ToList();

            //filteredResult = temp.Count;

            var result = temp.Select(x => new
            {
                url = x.url,
                appName = x.appName,
                location= x.location,
                contactName = x.contactName,
                contactRole = x.contactRole,
                server = x.server,
            }).ToList();

            CleanData(temp);

            return new JsonResult(new {draw = ajaxModel.draw, recordsTotal = totalResult, recordsFiltered = totalResult, data = result});
        }
```

Comment: what you have in your image, does it need to appear only in one row?

Comment: Yes, this is all one row